# Why MySQL threads sometimes stay in ‘killed’ state ?

Tags: mysql

Why MySQL threads sometimes stay in ‘killed’ state  ?

When i killed threads it always coming

what can i do for avoid threads killing state  in MYSQL .

Answer (score 2):

> Runningng the  `kill` command doesn’t actually do anything except for setting a special flag inside the selected thread. Therefore the kill operation doesn’t happen synchronously with the corresponding request. In many cases it takes some time for a thread or a query to stop. The flag is checked at various stages of statement execution. When it happens exactly, or how frequently, depends on the work a thread is actually doing.`

Please see [here](http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/05/15/why-do-threads-sometimes-stay-in-killed-state-in-mysql/) for a detailed information.